# can't create a websocket sever correctly by express-ws middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I'm writing a websocket server using node.js and express, and I use the express-ws middleware to help me. But the client can't connect the server.Below is my code.

app.js:

```
var app = express();
var expressWs = require("express-ws")(app);
...
var webso = require("./routes/ws");
app.use("/chat",webso);
```

routes/ws.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.ws("/",function(ws,req){
  console.log("socket from client")
  ws.on('message',function(msg){
    ws.send('back from node');
  })
});
module.exports=router;
```

the client:

```
wx.connectSocket({
        url:"ws://localhost:3000/chat",
        success(){
            console.log("success")
        },
        fail(){
            console.log("err")
        },
        complete(){
            console.log("done");
        }
    });
```

the client can't connect the websocket server:

```
asdebug.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/chat' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

I think something wrong I has made at the express server.I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing an `app.listen(3000)` in app.js to open that port? 
Websockets are just an upgrade to HTTP(s) so you can run on the same port as the rest of your routes.

Your server-side code is fine by the looks of it - not sure about client-side though. This works fine and outputs 'socket from client' when opened:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var expressWs = require("express-ws")(app);
var webso = require("./ws.js");
app.use("/chat",webso);
app.listen(3000);
```

ws.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.ws("/",function(ws,req){
  console.log("socket from client")
  ws.on('message',function(msg){
    ws.send('back from node');
  })
});
module.exports=router;
```

test.htm

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    websocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/chat');
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I did, and how to request server? 'ws://localhost:3000/chat' or 'http://localhost:3000/chat' ?

Comment: yes `ws://localhost:3000/chat` is right. hmmmm. Any error in node?

Comment: No, just the client can't connect it

Comment: I had a test, it's the problem of the server

Comment: why is this answer accepted if its now working for you?