# 404 error with express and express-ws

Tags: node.js, http, express, websocket

I'm having trouble trying to figure out why I'm getting this 404 error. I've gone through all the other questions on this site that cover 'express-ws' and i've modeled my code exactly how the solutions prescribed yet the websocket won't make a connection. I'm trying to create a websocket connection between my express server and react app. Below are previews of my code:

Express using express-ws (server.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var expressWs = require('express-ws');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var email = require('./credentials');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
var path = require('path');
// const WebSocket = require('ws');
// const http = require('http');

expressWs = expressWs(express());

let app = expressWs.app;

var server = require('http').createServer(app);

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('app/build'));
}

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  console.log('server running!');
  res.end();
});

app.ws('/ws', function(ws, req) {
  console.log( 'socket running!' );
});

server.listen(port);

console.log('server started on port ' + port);
```

The GET route works fine but the ws route doesn't.

Call to express from React app:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3001/ws');

  ws.on( 'open', function open() {
    console.log('app connected to websocket!');
  } );

  ws.on( 'message', function ( message ) {
    console.log( message );
  })
}
```

[image: Console log of GET error from ws call:]

I've looked at all the following questions and don't understand why their solutions don't work for me:

- [Socket.IO 404 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795708/socket-io-returns-404-error-with-express-http)
- [express-ws connection problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438048/cant-create-a-websocket-sever-correctly-by-express-ws-middleware)
- [Node not working with express-ws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764640/node-server-not-working-with-express-ws)

If anyone can let me know what's going on that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code does not follow `express-ws`'s [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws). To use `express-ws` and make WebSocket endpoint, the code would be as:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);
...
app.ws('/', function(ws, req) {
  ws.on('message', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  });
  console.log('socket running');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

In the client side, `ws` object does not have field `on`. To listen WebSocket connection and message, you can use `onopen` and `onmessage`:

```
ws.onopen = function() {
  console.log('app connected to websocket!');
};
ws.onmessage = function(message) {
  console.log( message );
};
```

Comment: I fail to see how the first part, functionally differs from the code provided by the OP which supposedly "does not follow express-ws's document".  The only thing is you seem to have changed the endpoint from "/ws" to "/" which seems inconsequential to me.  Can you explain exactly what was wrong in the original question that you corrected?

Comment: Looks like the `ws.on('message', ...)` part is missed in the OP's post? This answer is provided 5 years ago, so I'm not familiar with the detail any more :(

Comment: ah gotcha, i thought there was a difference in the first part

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and for me the solution was to change:

```
server.listen(port);
```

to:

```
app.listen(port);
```

I suspect what is going on is that express-ws is using the app listen function as its cue to start upgrading connections to ws and this won't happen if the server listen port occurs instead.